# Creating and populating table view in normal view controller

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, datasource

I bet this question has been asked a thousand times, but I wasn't able to find one that directly relates to the problem I'm having right now, so I'd really appreciate some help from you guys. Here goes:

I have a view controller in my iPhone application that, when triggered, requests a JSON string from a server. When the app receives the JSON it gets parsed, and a table view is populated with the corresponding data. While this is taking place, I'm showing a `UIActivityIndicatorView` to indicate that something is going on behind the scenes.

I can download and parse the JSON just fine, but when it comes to populating the table view, I'm pretty lost. Since I have to display a completely white view and not an empty table view with an activity indicator on it, I haven't made my view controller a subclass of UITableViewController (which by default displays an empty list).

How do I create and populate a table view with the data that I've downloaded from the server, and how do I do it without the normal `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and those kinds of methods?

Thanks!

**Solution**

I just figured out how to solve my problem. When the server response has returned, I allocate my table view, set its datasource and delegate to `self`, then populate the table view with the returned data by implementing the same methods that a UITableViewController implements. Remember, as @Deepak points out, to adopt the `UITableViewDatasource` and `UITableViewDelegate` in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you can't use a `UITableViewController` subclass and do

```
// Create UIActivityIndicatorView instance
[self.view addSubview:activityIndicatorView];
```

If you need an empty white view, you can also add it as a subview here.

As such if you are interested in continuing in the current way. You will need to have your `UIViewController` subclass adopt the `UITableViewDatasource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols and implement the appropriate methods. I don't think you can use a `UITableView` without doing that.

**Edit**

It is very strange that when you take out the NIB, this behaves differently. If you change the number of rows to even `1`, the overlay shows correctly. This seems to be a bug.

I suggest that you implement `loadView` to fix this where you separate `self.view` and `self.tableView`.

```
- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];
    self.tableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: I'd love to use `UITableViewController`, but when I hide the table view (with `hidden` or `alpha`), it seems as if I'm hiding the entire view. So, if I'm adding a subview to `self.view` it's not shown unless the table view is visible.

Comment: Yes. Edited out that suggestion. `self.view` is synonymous to `self.tableView` in a `UITableViewController`. Try adding an `UIView` instance with a white `backgroundColor` on top of the table view.

Comment: No luck. The view appears beneath the table view, so the table view cell's separating lines are visible on top of the subview, like so: http://cl.ly/3K3R161q0X2x2E2o401C

Comment: How about `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.whiteOverlay];`?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. It's still placed beneath the table view.

Comment: In viewDidLoad, I do this: `UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)]; myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; [self.view addSubview:myView]; [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myView];`. I've given the view a blue background color, so I can easily tell where it's placed.

Comment: [`Here`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/TableOverlay.zip)'s what I tried. It seems to work fine. Can you tell what I have done different or if you can provide some sample code to look at, then I can help you further with this.

Comment: That's very weird. The code looks exactly the same. I don't use Interface Builder, though, so maybe that's part of the problem. I've looked through your .xib file, but I can't seem to find anything that relates to this in particular. Maybe you have en idea what it could be?

Comment: Since you aren't using `IB`, can you provide the code for `loadView`? It will give an idea on how you are setting it up.

Comment: There's no method called `loadView` in my view controller. As far as I can tell, it isn't necessary in a subclass of UITableViewController.

Comment: Aah! I can reproduce your problem now. Let me look into it.

Comment: It's very strange. Probably a bug too. I've updated the post with an approach to fix this.

Comment: Your loadView method doesn't seem to change anything, but the more sections I have, the more of the subview is shown correctly. This seems like somewhat of a dirty workaround. Besides, when I edit the table view immediately to take care of these problems, how can I repopulate it with the data from the server? I'm sure there is a solution to this, but the messier it gets, the more I feel like just going back to a normal UIViewController.

Comment: It does feel like a dirty workaround too. This is what you would do with a normal view controller too, right? Or do you intend to add `UITableView` as its subview? And what about repopulating the data from server? Isn't it download data in the background thread and then update the table view i.e. `[self.tableView reloadData];` in the main thread?